# Display a nested array value from fetch data in console

Tags: javascript, react-native

I m using fetch api to call data from the server,the data is received as nested arrays, and i want to display an attribut 'nom' in my console.log but i can t figure out how to do it.
my code looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    
    fetch('*******')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("!!!test proches")
            console.log(res.proches[0])
            console.log("!!!!!!!!!")
            
        })
        .done();
  }
```

and this is what i get on my console:

[image]

i tried doing console.log(res.proches[0].nom) but i get undefined.
I'm new to react native or javascript and i would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you res.proches[0], that too returns an array. Try pulling the first object from that array out and then use the . notation, like this :

```
console.log(res.proches[0][0].nom)
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)